# Get data type for DataRow[myColumn] and cast another variable as that type

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a class that needs to have a variable of an unknown numeric type.  I need to get the data type from a specific column at run time, then cast/instantiate the class variable as that type, and then keep a running total of that column as I iterate rows.  I thought about representing my class variable as `dynamic`, but that doesn't sit right with me.  I also thought about using a generic method, but again, I feel like there's a better way to do this.  A generic property would be great, but, well, you know how that story ends.

Updated, here's what's left of the code I've been working with:

```
dynamic dc = dataRow["MyColumnName"];
var tempValue = Convert.ChangeType(dataRow["MyColumnName"], Type.GetType(dc.GetType().ToString())); 
total+= (Decimal)tempValue;
```

Comment: Could you provide your tried code

Comment: that's weird, why you dont know the type of column "MyColumnName"?

Comment: It could be passed in as an int, decimal, long, etc.

Comment: you cant modify datarow, datarow datatypes are defined by datacolumn. You have to spesify the column datatype then, rows will be modified. But these datas are read only. You should do it when creating. I will share a sample block for always string.

 foreach (Cell cell in rows.ElementAt(0))
            {
                DataColumn col = new DataColumn(GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, cell));
                col.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
                dt.Columns.Add(col);
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving it like this:

```
public int MyMethod<T>(DataTable myDataTable)
{
    dynamic myTempVariable = default(T);
    ...
}
```

It's not a perfect solution (I didn't want to have to know the column data type before calling the method), but this gives me the flexibility I wanted inside of the method.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
if (dtRow.Table.Columns["Date"].DataType == typeof(System.DateTime))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is Solution to check if a data row item in table contains Null value on the bases of row item type

```
       Dim ds as New DataSet = MYData()
       Dim rowindex As Integer = 0
       For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
         For index As Integer = 0 To row.ItemArray.Length - 1
             If (TypeOf row(index) Is DBNull) And (IsDBNull(row(index))) Then
                ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowindex)(index) = 0
             End If
         Next
         rowindex = rowindex + 1
        Next
```